# Equivalent moment using Rainflow

Tags: matlab, time-series

I am trying to make a fatigue analysis from a load series and I woudl like to extract the equivalent moment for

```
number cycles=1000000
years=25
```

I have a time series for one hour that looks like:

[image]

Then I have read that Rainflow Analysis is a very good tool to extract the cycles from a time history. Therefore I apply:

```
%Rainflow moment
dt=time(2)-time(1);
[timeSeriesSig, extt] = sig2ext(timeSeries, dt);
rf = rainflow(timeSeriesSig,extt);
```

I read that
  OUTPUT
    rf - rainflow cycles: matrix 3xn or 5xn dependend on input,
      rf(1,:) Cycles amplitude,
      rf(2,:) Cycles mean value,
      rf(3,:) Number of cycles (0.5 or 1.0),
      rf(4,:) Begining time (when input includes dt or extt data),
      rf(5,:) Cycle period (when input includes dt or extt data),

If I am interested in the number of cycles what does the term rf(3,:) mean? It is only containing 0.5 and 1 in the vector. I want to obtain an histogram with the number of cycles per bin amplitude. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code from the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3026-rainflow-counting-algorithm) or another source, it helps to link to where you obtained it.

Here, `rf(3,:)` is showing you whether the amplitudes and other outputs refer to half or full cycles.  The rainflow algorithm finds half-cycles first, and then matches tensile and compressive half-cycles of equal amplitude to find full cycles.  There are normally some residual half-cycles.

If you examine the `rfhist` function contained within that same File Exchange submission, you will see how they handle full and half amplitudes. Basically, two half-cycles at any given load amplitude will be counted as one full cycle when creating the histogram.